# jQuery swap image on hover, then replace it with original on hover off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code to swap an image src out on hover of the child's parent. How can I save the original source in a variable and on hover off return the image to its original source?

```
      $("#parent span").hover(function(){
          var currentImage = $('img', this ).attr("src","images/orbs/yellowBar.png");
          $('img', this ).attr("src","images/yellowBar.png");


        },function(){

          $('img', this ).attr("src",currentImage);

      });
```

Comment: Try saving it to a global variable. so, outside of that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `currentImage` outside of your function:

```
var currentImage;

$("#parent span").hover(function() {
    currentImage = $('img', this).attr("src", "images/orbs/yellowBar.png");
    $('img', this).attr("src", "images/yellowBar.png");
}, function() {
    $('img', this).attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

Comment: Pretty easy and pretty error-prone due to global variable. In addition it's also incorrect since `currentImage` is an object in this case.

Comment: I agree with @dfsq a global variable does not seem to be the best option in this case because as stated it could accidently be overwritten.

Comment: While I do agree also, it was only important to show the most basic example to express the principle to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, the better way is to create two css classes with different background image and don't use javascript/jquery for image switch on hover at all.

css:

```
.time-stamp-img {
    background:url('images/time_stamp_list_icon_play.png');
}
.time-stamp-img:hover {
    background:url('images/time_stamp_list_icon_hover.png');
}
```

html:

```
<div class="time-stamp-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use https://api.jquery.com/data/ and just set a data point on the element of the original source, and then just retrieve it on mouse out.

Comment: This is actually how it should be done properly, not sure why it's downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dylan Watt's suggestion I'd use `.data()` to avoid a global variable.

So something like this:

```
$("span").mouseenter(function () {
    var currentImage = $('img', this).attr("src");
    $('img', this).data("orig", currentImage)
    .attr("src", "http://placehold.it/350x150&text=hover");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    var original = $('img', this).data("orig");
    $('img', this).attr("src", original);
});
```

And here's the fiddle that's from that you can adapt for your use:

http://jsfiddle.net/djfe7rum/1/

Comment: It can be improved by reducing DOM queries. You can chain jQuery calls and avoid reselecting `$('img', this)` several times.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using mouseenter, mouseleave, as such:

```
var currentImage;
$("#parent span").mouseenter(function(){
    currentImage = $('img', this ).attr("src");
    $('img', this ).attr("src","images/yellowBar.png");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('img', this ).attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

If this doesn't work, please provide your HTML code.